# p:dataTable with p:columns with custom widths

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Datatable with dynamic columns via the  `p:columns` tag and want to specify a different width for each column.

My code is as below

```
<p:dataTable id="scheduleDataTable" value="#{scheduleMB.scheduledRecords}" var="sched" rows="10">
        <p:columns value="#{scheduleMB.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" styleClass="day-column">  
            <f:facet name="header">
                #{column.header}
            </f:facet>

            #{sched[column.property]}
        </p:columns>  
    </p:dataTable>
```

in the css file I have the width

```
.ui-state-default .day-column{
 width: 150px !important;
}
```

i even tried styld="width:150px;" both of them doesn't work, the columns are drawn with default values.

but i want different column widths, how do i do it.
I tried like specifying multiple css in styleClass="col1,col2", specifying in facet like

```
<f:facet name="style">
    #{column.size}
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 2):

The official way to set the column width for the PrimeFaces `DataTable` is to define the `width` attribute of the `column` element using a unitless integer. Like this:

```
<p:column width="70">
    <h:outputText value="#{element.prop}" />
</p:column>
```

You can use EL to let the controller define the width.

The advice applies to the 3.3 and 3.4 versions of PF and may be different for older ones. The details have changed several times over the last few version updates, so you may also wwant to consult the [migration guide](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)

Comment: I use 3.3, i have used the width option earlier for single columns but i wanted to know if there is anyway i can have variable width columns with the p:columns option

Comment: Setting the p:column width param seems not to have any effect on my layout

Comment: In Primefaces 6, the `width` can also take a percentage like "70%".

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width of each column with EL  width="#{column.width}". Your column class needs have a width property.

```
<p:dataTable id="scheduleDataTable" value="#{scheduleMB.scheduledRecords}" var="sched" rows="10">
    <p:columns value="#{scheduleMB.columns}" var="column" 
      width="#{column.width}" 
      columnIndexVar="colIndex" styleClass="day-column">  
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{column.header}
        </f:facet>

        #{sched[column.property]}
    </p:columns>  
</p:dataTable>
```