# Primefaces p:columns individual with of columns

Tags: primefaces

When using p:columns inside a datatable, all columns have the same width. Is there an easy way to define different widths for each column.

I tried to wrap the outputtext inside an panelGrid, but that doesn't solved the problem.

Thanks for any advice!

```
<p:columns value="#{Bean.columns}" var="column" >
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" width="#{Bean.settings.width(column.property)}">
        <h:outputText value="blabla" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:columns>
```

Comment: Try adding style attribute to the columns. `style="width:5px"`

Comment: sry does not work, width of all columns stay constant

Comment: @MasterChief will that make all column's 5px?

Comment: Why if the panelgrid does not solve the problem do you put it in the source in the question? And why do you think 'width' on panelgrid works? Where in the showcase/docs or tutorial did you read that? Did you try giving the outputText a width? So many easy things to try...

Comment: And did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370006/primeface-datatable-with-custom-column-widths?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you very much, the question is exactly what i was looking for... i googled for it and searched in SO, but didn't find it. thx!!!